# Can I transfer money to other main characters?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I wanted to transfer money from my richest main character to the others for them to buy properties. Is there a way to transfer money to other characters?

Comment: tbh I doubt it. But try going to the internet, financial part, then choose a bank that your character is using and try to transfer money from there. I will try it tomorrow and let you know if this works(if you won't enlighten us before)

Comment: This isn't possible.  Use the missions to your advantage by investing in Stocks.

Comment: @Ramhound - You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, each character's bank account is their own. Think of it this way, if you were pulling heists in IRL with a character like Trevor, do you really want him having access to your cut? Or do you think Trevor would want to share Michael or Franklin, I think not.

Comment: I would agree to your analogy, specially with Trevor's personality lol